# How does this case blend prediction above and why divide all train data into two part?

Tags: python, pandas, prediction, xgboost

I am new in this field and trying to read some code to do my homework
https://github.com/auduno/Kaggle-Acquire-Valued-Shoppers-Challenge/blob/master/generate_submission.py

In this case, the programmer divide the whole train data into two part and only use one part to train and predict another part. I am confused about this, together with the test part.

```
test_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv("./features/test/all_features.csv", sep=" ")
train_data = pd.io.parsers.read_csv("./features/train/all_features.csv", sep=" ")

split = ShuffleSplit(train_data.shape[0], n_iter = 1, test_size=0.10)
for tr, te in split:
    train1, train2 = tr, te
```

Also, in the blend part, I can't understand the process it put all prediction data together. `pred_train` and `pred_test` are all data predicted but he use it to train again? Could you explain about that? Thanks a lot.

```
############### BLEND


dtrain2 = xgb.DMatrix( pred_train, label=train2_label.values)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix( pred_test )

print "training blend : xgb trees booster logistic regression, max depth 2"
param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':0.1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic', 'nthread' : 8, 'eval_metric':'auc' }
num_round = 50
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain2, num_round)

pred_label_test = bst.predict( dtest )

print "training blend : xgb linear booster logistic regression"
param = {'booster_type':1, 'bst:lambda':0, 'bst:alpha':0, 'bst:lambda_bias':0, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic', 'nthread' : 8, 'eval_metric':'auc' }
num_round = 25
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain2, num_round)

pred_label = bst.predict( dtest )       

mean_pred = (pred_label + pred_label_test)/2.

predictions[r] = mean_pred
```

Comment: Why don't you ask your instructor? This isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: ok, then, which is more relevant?

Answer (score 0):

In machine learning a common problem is overfitting. If you check classification quality with the same set that you use for training, then algorithms have tendency to train for that particular set. They learn features that are specific only for that set. So common practice is to divide data to a set used for training and a set used for checking that classification is correct.

The `BLEND` part of your code uses two different machine learning algorithms and then blends their result by taking mean value. That way author tries to minimize regression error in a hope that different algorithms make different mistakes.

Comment: Could you be more specific, say, which line is doing the key function. It seems in the train2 the predicted label is deserted and where to check?

Comment: The code is quite self explanatory. Try reading it like English text. `bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain2, num_round)` trains a model using `param` as training parameters and `strain2` as training set. The model is stored in `bst`. `pred_label_test = bst.predict( dtest )` predicts output value for `stest` set and stores result in `pred_label_test`.  Variable names `pred_label_test` and `pred_label` are not a good choice because they do not represent what is actually stored in them. And that confuses you.